# Variable elimination in Z3

Tags: python, variables, z3, solver, smt

After solving a constraint system using z3 I get a model where some variables are set to None (I'm using Pyz3). Does it mean that those variables have been eliminated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unassigned variables should be interpreted as "don't cares". That is, any assignment would satisfy the input formula.
Here is a small example (also available [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/zlHh)). The assignment produced by Z3 only assigns `x` to `1`. The value of `y` doesn't matter.

```
(set-option :auto-config false)
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)
(assert (or (= x 1) (= y 1)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```